# EntityFramework Fluent API Foreign Key ordering

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

How to set column order for foreign key properties, so all columns will be generated in my custom order rather than default alphabetical one?

I want to use pure code first aproach without any annotation attributes and I don't want to include foreign key id columns (like UserId, RoleId etc) in my entity.

Let's say I have following configuration class:

```
public class UserRoleEntityConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<UserRole>
{
    public UserRoleEntityConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(p => p.User).WithMany(p => p.Roles);
        HasOptional(p => p.Company).WithMany(p => p.Users);
        HasRequired(p => p.Role).WithMany(p => p.Users);
    }
}
```

EF will generate following table:

```
create table [dbo].[UserRoles] (
[Id] [int] not null identity,
...
[CompanyId] [int] null,
[RoleId] [int] not null,
[UserId] [int] not null,
primary key ([Id]));
```

But I want:

```
create table [dbo].[UserRoles] (
[Id] [int] not null identity,
...
[UserId] [int] not null,    
[CompanyId] [int] null,
[RoleId] [int] not null,
primary key ([Id]));
```

**UPDATE:**
Found a workaround using protected foreign key properties:

```
public class UserRole : AuditableEntity<int>
{
    protected int? CompanyId { get; set; }

    protected int RoleId { get; set; }

    protected int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public class AccessExpressions
    {
        public static readonly Expression<Func<UserRole, int?>> CompanyId = x => x.CompanyId;
        public static readonly Expression<Func<UserRole, int>> RoleId = x => x.RoleId;
        public static readonly Expression<Func<UserRole, int>> UserId = x => x.UserId;
    }
}

public class UserRoleEntityConfiguration: EntityTypeConfiguration<UserRole>
{
    public UserRoleEntityConfiguration()
    {
        Property(UserRole.AccessExpressions.UserId).HasColumnOrder(8);
        HasRequired(p => p.User).WithMany(p => p.Roles).HasForeignKey(UserRole.AccessExpressions.UserId);

        Property(UserRole.AccessExpressions.CompanyId).HasColumnOrder(9);
        HasOptional(p => p.Company).WithMany(p => p.Users).HasForeignKey(UserRole.AccessExpressions.CompanyId);

        Property(UserRole.AccessExpressions.RoleId).HasColumnOrder(10);
        HasRequired(p => p.Role).WithMany(p => p.Users).HasForeignKey(UserRole.AccessExpressions.RoleId);
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, without foreign key properties you can't do that.
Why do you want to omit them? You can do FK properties `protected`, if you don't want to set them from outside of the model.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I want to omit them to have a clear object model interface. Having navigation property and foreign key property in the same class makes a Frankenstein entity :) Your idea with hiding them under `protected` is good actually. I will add this workaround into question.

Comment: Quite simply, some believe that database keys should not be exposed at all. That way, if there are changes to the database structure, you don't need to fix that. Db Keys change more often than I could ever hope... in my experience.